# Azure web deploy using Linux operating system causes unauthorised token error

Tags: c#, linux, azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've just deployed my React, .NetCore application with the pre configured identity server on Azure web apps. When I deploy with Linux operating system every time I log in and try to access a Authorised route I get an unauthorised error, I assume that there is something causing identity server token to create this error. Its odd because when I deploy with the windows configuration this does not occur as it also does not occur in my development environment. I am just wondering if anyone has encountered this identity server token issue occuring when deploying a web application on Azure web app through the Linux operating system? [Image of choosing Linux operating system in Azure web apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoqZI.png)

Comment: Take a look at this - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-ssh/ba-p/392548

Comment: Hi, I've reworded my question, I believe it has something to do with the token generation on Linux compared to Windows web app deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved it and it seems that I had to add "https_port": 443 to my appsettings.json.